# Yii- How To Get Dropdownlist Option Values Same As The Text In The List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yii, yii-extensions

I'm new to Yii framework. I created a dropdownlist using the below code -

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'min_cost', Yii::app()->params['cost_resales']);
```

This generated a HTML like -

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost" name="SearchForm[min_cost]" >
<option value="">Min</option>
<option value="0">Min Cost</option>
<option value="1">10 lakhs</option>
<option value="2">20 lakhs</option>
<option value="3">30 lakhs</option>
<option value="4">40 lakhs</option>
<option value="5">50 lakhs</option>
</select>
```

But, I don't know how to get it like this -

```
<select id="SearchForm_min_cost" name="SearchForm[min_cost]" >
<option value="">Min</option>
<option value="Min Cost">Min Cost</option>
<option value="10 lakhs">10 lakhs</option>
<option value="20 lakhs">20 lakhs</option>
<option value="30 lakhs">30 lakhs</option>
<option value="40 lakhs">40 lakhs</option>
<option value="50 lakhs">50 lakhs</option>
</select>
```

I want the option values same as that in the text. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify them in `value => text` pairs:

```
'cost_resales' => array(
    'Min Cost' => 'Min Cost',
    '10 lakhs' => '10 lakhs',
    '20 lakhs' => '20 lakhs',
    '30 lakhs' => '30 lakhs',
    '40 lakhs' => '40 lakhs',
    '50 lakhs' => '50 lakhs',
),
```

Same for radio buttons:

```
$form->radioButtonList($model, 'isPublished', array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No'));
```

Another example:

```
$form->dropButtonList($model, 'favouriteFood', array('apple' => 'Apple', 'orange' => 'Orange', 'banana' => 'Banana'));
```